# Downloading Storing And Mixing The .ts files Correct Way in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to download streams form a server and those streams are stored as chunks  in .ts files.

I want to download all those .ts files and convert them to mp4 for offline viewing.
I am able to download the .m3u8` file which contains info about the resolution and other info and info about number of chunks.

I am thinking to download all the .ts files and store them on local storage and then convert them to .mp4 but it will take up to twice of orignal size of the video as it will store the chunks and original till converting which is not good i think.

Is there is any way to download the video like in one go for example, download the .ts stream and store and convert to the mp4 file and delete it and repeat till the last file so the space required will be same as the original video file size.

Is there is any library or downloader which can download theses streams and automaticly convert them to mp4 extension ?

or any better way to download these stream to mp4 without being resource hungry ?

Comment: Is this from a live stream with rolling DVR window or does the m3u8 file have a definite beginning and end (ending with #EXT-X-ENDLIST).

Comment: yes this have a list. a total of 2000 .ts files

Answer (score 2):

You accomplish this with FFmpeg.

Here is a command line to convert an HLS playlist (hosted on a remote server) to a local MP4 file.

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

[This sample](https://github.com/hadifar/Downloader-M3u8) may help you, it need just your m3u8 url.
Btw, does anyone have solution for joining many ts url to one url without downloading anything?